No serializa con jackson, en proyecto rest con spring
Tengo dos microservicios rest, con uno quiero leer en el endpoint de otro.
Esta es la clase a serializar y deserializar
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Persona {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
}

Me tira esta excepción:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.example.domain.Persona and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

si pongo esto encima de cada campo funciona: @JsonProperty("id") y lo mismo si pongo los setters y getters a mano pero no es lo más correcto. Entiendo que es un problema de compatibilidad entre lombok y jackson pero no veo nada.
La version de lombok es 1.18.34
Y de jackson la incorporo con spring-boot-starter-web
Lo hago así:
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@GetMapping("/pp")
public Persona[] personas(){
    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/personas/all", Persona[].class);
}


intenta implementar las interface java.io.Serializable o directamente no uses esa anotación debería funcionar correctamente sin ella

te recomiendo intentar usar la interface serializadle ya que el BeanSerializer es el que esta fallando,
import java.io.Serializable;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Persona implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
}

te voy a enseñar un ejemplo que me funciona a mi sin necesidad de usar esa anotación:
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UsuarioDTO {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String nombreCompleto;
    private String correo;
    private boolean usarNombreCompleto;
    private String iconPath;
}
@PostMapping("/crear")
    public ResponseEntity<UsuarioDTO> crearUsuario(@RequestBody UsuarioDTO usuarioDTO) {
        UsuarioDTO nuevoUsuario = usuarioService.crearUsuario(usuarioDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(nuevoUsuario);
    }

ahora te muestro un ejemplo con arreglos pero en forma de listas para mas facilidad
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MensajeDTO {
    private int id;
    private String correoEmisor;
    private String mensaje;
    private Mensaje.TipoMensaje tipo; // enum
    private Timestamp fechaEnvio;
    private String archivoPath;
}

@GetMapping("/obtener")
        public ResponseEntity<List<MensajeDTO>> obtenerMensajes(
                @RequestParam String correoReceptor, HttpSession session) {

            String userCorreo = (String) session.getAttribute(LoginController.USER_CORREO);

            if (userCorreo != null) {
                List<MensajeDTO> mensajes = mensajePrivadoService.obtenerMensajesEntreUsuarios(userCorreo, correoReceptor);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(mensajes);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(401).build(); // Retorna un error 401 si no hay usuario en sesión
            }
        }

puedes intentar ver el json antes de convertirlos a objetos para ver que este correctamente estructurado como un arreglo
como puedes ver estos ejemplo no usan esa anotación.
otra cosa que puedes hacer usar librerías especializadas que convierten string json a objetos como Gson
